# Trouble writing to file with SMBJ

Tags: java, windows, smbj

Please help. I am unable to create and write to a file using SMBJ. I'm getting this error:

```
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0xc0000034): Create failed for <file path>
```

Is this a Windows errors or an SMBJ error? Am I using the SMBJ API correctly? I don't understand Windows file attributes/options well.

```
String fileName ="EricTestFile.txt";
String fileContents = "Mary had a little lamb.";

SMBClient client = new SMBClient();
try (Connection connection = client.connect(serverName)) {
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(username, password.toCharArray(), domain);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);

    // Connect to Share
    try (DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sharename)) {
        for (FileIdBothDirectoryInformation f : share.list(folderName, "*.*")) {
            System.out.println("File : " + f.getFileName());
        }

        //share.openFile(path, accessMask, attributes, shareAccesses, createDisposition, createOptions)
        Set<FileAttributes> fileAttributes = new HashSet<>();
        fileAttributes.add(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
        Set<SMB2CreateOptions> createOptions = new HashSet<>();
        createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_RANDOM_ACCESS);
        File f = share.openFile(folderName+"\\"+fileName, new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new AccessMask[]{AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL})), fileAttributes, SMB2ShareAccess.ALL, SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OVERWRITE, createOptions);

        OutputStream oStream = f.getOutputStream();
        oStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you read this/had the hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2628582/status-object-name-not-found-error-message-when-you-open-a-newly-creat ?

Answer (score 3):

If the file that you're trying to open does not yet exist, you need to use a different `SMB2CreateDisposition`. You're now using `FILE_OVERWRITE`, which is documented as:

> Overwrite the file if it already exists; otherwise, fail the operation. MUST NOT be used for a printer object.

You probably want to use `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF`, which does:

> Overwrite the file if it already exists; otherwise, create the file. This value SHOULD NOT be used for a printer object.